# Wordpress $_GET parameters (from the URL) using two values of same custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to return both the properties with the status of both 'sold' and 'leased'. I have successfully been able to return either the 'sold' or 'leased' properties, but not yet both.

I have added the following to my functions file:

```
// FILTER PROPERTIES BY STATUS //

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

  // do not modify queries in the admin
  if( is_admin() ) {

    return $query;

  }


  // only modify queries for 'event' post type
  if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'properties' ) {

// allow the url to alter the query
if( isset($_GET['status']) ) {

    $query->set('meta_key', 'status');
  $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['status']);

      } 

  }


  // return
   return $query;

 }

 add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

The url format I am using to successfully return either the 'sold' or 'leased' properties is:

http://www.example.com/properties/?status=leased

or

http://www.example.com/properties/?status=sold

Is there a simple URL format I can use to include both values? I have tried for example:

http://www.example.com/properties/?status=leased&status=sold

Or is there a change to the function I need to make first?

Comment: status[]=leased&status[]=sold should work (and then get it as status)

Comment: Thanks Mindastic. Do you mean for the URL format? What's that character you have after 'status'?

Comment: It makes status be an array of values instead just one.

Comment: So I need to make a change to the function then?

Comment: Nope, you shouldn't need to do any change on the backend unless you want to store each value as separated metadata and not as an array.

Comment: So you're suggesting the following URL should work?

http://www.example.com/properties/?status=leased&status=sold

Comment: Nope. I didn't say that. Please, check the comments above. It shows how the url should be.

Comment: Your original reply shows what seems to be illegal characters in your proposed URL? As i asked, what are they meant to be? They are showing as squares.

Comment: They are not squares. They are square brackets.

Comment: That URL doesn't work.